# How to Enable Dynamic Compression in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, compression, httpresponse

How to Enable Dynamic Compression in Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager in Windows 7?
The answer is below. Couldn't find it anywhere here.

Answer (score 1):

If enabling dynamic compression in Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager is not possible because it is not installed, click start, in the search box, write "Windows Features", click Turn "Windows features on or off." 
Under Internet Information Services --> World Wide Web Services --> Performance Features
--> Enable Dynamic Content Compression.

Source: [phejndorf](http://phejndorf.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/windows-7-the-dynamic-content-compression-module-is-not-installed/)